# How to prevent the default embedded mongodb from being downloaded

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using version 2.0.0 of [flapdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) to run embedded mongo integration tests in a Java Springboot application.

In a `@DataMongoTest` test case I am working on, I am using the MongodConfigBuilder to set a specific version:

```
mongodExe = starter.prepare(new MongodConfigBuilder()
        .version(Versions.withFeatures(new GenericVersion("3.4.2"), Feature.SYNC_DELAY))
        .net(new Net("localhost", 12345, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build());
```

Later, I am also creating an IRuntimeConfig to set a custom downloadUrl to ensure all dependencies are from within my local network. This all works as expected and the specified embedded mongodb/version is pulled from the URL I am specifying. However, before it does this, it downloads what must be the default version of mongo as well (currently 3.2.2):

For example:

```
{"message":"Download 3.2.2:OS_X:B64 : 10 %","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO"}
{"message":"Download 3.2.2:OS_X:B64 : 20 %","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO"}
{"message":"Download 3.2.2:OS_X:B64 : 30 %","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO"}
```

What do I need to set so the default version will not be downloaded? It is not used, so it is unnecessary, and it is pulling from an external resource which I want to avoid.